# Adicionar Endpoint na aplicação Web

Tags: php, javascript, html, api

Como utilizar adicionar Endpoint em uma aplicação web que consome a API criada com o Microsoft Custon Voice.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
  <!-- <uidiv> -->
  <div id="warning">
    <h1 style="font-weight:500;">Speech Recognition Speech SDK not found (microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js missing).</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content" style="display:none">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><h1 style="font-weight:500;">Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</h1></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started" target="_blank">Subscription</a>:</td>
        <td><input id="subscriptionKey" type="text" size="40" value="subscription"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Region</td>
        <td><input id="serviceRegion" type="text" size="40" value="YourServiceRegion"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><button id="startSpeakTextAsyncButton">Start text to speech</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Input Text</td>
        <td><textarea id="phraseDiv" style="display: inline-block;width:500px;height:200px"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Result</td>
        <td><textarea id="resultDiv" style="display: inline-block;width:500px;height:100px"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- </uidiv> -->

  <!-- <speechsdkref> -->
  <!-- Speech SDK reference sdk. -->
  <script src="microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- </speechsdkref> -->

  <!-- <authorizationfunction> -->
  <!-- Speech SDK Authorization token -->
  <script>
  // Note: Replace the URL with a valid endpoint to retrieve
  //       authorization tokens for your subscription.
  var authorizationEndpoint = "token.php";

  function RequestAuthorizationToken() {
    if (authorizationEndpoint) {
      var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
      a.open("GET", authorizationEndpoint);
      a.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      a.send("");
      a.onload = function() {
        var token = JSON.parse(atob(this.responseText.split(".")[1]));
        serviceRegion.value = token.region;
        authorizationToken = this.responseText;
        subscriptionKey.disabled = true;
        subscriptionKey.value = "using authorization token (hit F5 to refresh)";
        console.log("Got an authorization token: " + token);
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
  <!-- </authorizationfunction> -->

  <!-- <quickstartcode> -->
  <!-- Speech SDK USAGE -->
  <script>
        
    // status fields and start button in UI
    var phraseDiv;
    var resultDiv;
    var startSpeakTextAsyncButton;

    // subscription key and region for speech services.
    var subscriptionKey, serviceRegion;
    var authorizationToken;
    var SpeechSDK;
    var synthesizer;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      startSpeakTextAsyncButton = document.getElementById("startSpeakTextAsyncButton");
      subscriptionKey = document.getElementById("subscriptionKey");
      serviceRegion = document.getElementById("serviceRegion");
      phraseDiv = document.getElementById("phraseDiv");
      resultDiv = document.getElementById("resultDiv");

      startSpeakTextAsyncButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var soundContext = undefined;
        try {
          var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || false;
          if (AudioContext) {
            soundContext = new AudioContext();
          } else {
            alert("AudioContext not supported");
          }
        }
        catch(e){
          window.console.log("no sound context found, no audio output. " + e);
        }
   
        startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = true;
        phraseDiv.innerHTML = "";

        // if we got an authorization token, use the token. Otherwise use the provided subscription key
        var speechConfig;
        if (authorizationToken) {
          speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromAuthorizationToken(authorizationToken, serviceRegion.value);
        } else {
          if (subscriptionKey.value === "" || subscriptionKey.value === "subscription") {
            alert("Please enter your Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech subscription key!");
            startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
            return;
          }
          speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey.value, serviceRegion.value);
        }

        synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);

        var inputText = phraseDiv.value;
        synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
          inputText,      
          function (result) {
            startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
            resultDiv.innerHTML += "Result: ";
            resultDiv.innerHTML += result.text;
            resultDiv.innerHTML += "\n";

            window.console.log(result);
            if (result.audioData && soundContext) {
              var source = soundContext.createBufferSource();
              soundContext.decodeAudioData(result.audioData, function (newBuffer) {
                source.buffer = newBuffer;
                source.connect(soundContext.destination);
                source.start(0);
              });
            }

            synthesizer.close();
            synthesizer = undefined;
          },
          function (err) {
            startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
            resultDiv.innerHTML += "Error: ";
            resultDiv.innerHTML += err;
            resultDiv.innerHTML += "\n";
            window.console.log(err);

            synthesizer.close();
            synthesizer = undefined;
          });
      });

      if (!!window.SpeechSDK) {
        SpeechSDK = window.SpeechSDK;
        startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;

        document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'none';

        // in case we have a function for getting an authorization token, call it.
        if (typeof RequestAuthorizationToken === "function") {
          RequestAuthorizationToken();
        }
      }
    });
  
  
  </script>
  <!-- </quickstartcode> -->
</body>
</html>
```

token.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

// Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
$subscriptionKey = 'Token----------';
$region = 'brazilsouth';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . $region . '.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ' . $subscriptionKey));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo curl_exec($ch);
?>
```